# JS: Attach a clicklistener when generating a select-option

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project with the object of creating an online pizza delivery service have  Element called pizzaPreviewList, which gets filled with data from an Array pizzas.

Now I want to delete an Item in pizzaPreviewList, when it is clicked. My approach was as follows.

Shopping cart renders:

```
self.render = function () {
        self.pizzaPreviewElement.innerHTML = "";
        for(var k in self.pizzas) {
            var element = self.pizzas[k].getElement();
            self.pizzaPreviewElement.appendChild(element);
        }
    };
```

Pizza creates new Option Item in get Element():

```
self.getElement = function () {
        var elementContainer = document.createElement('option');
        elementContainer.innerHTML = '<span>'+ self.name + '    ' + self.preis.toFixed(2) + '€</span>';
        elementContainer.addEventListener('click', onClick());

        return elementContainer;
    };
```

onClick is then supposed to run a method that removes the Pizza and rerenders, but onClick is automatically called when the element is created and my Array goes nuts, because it tries to delete things that are not there yet. How do I solve this?

No use of Frameworks is allowed.

Comment: Need HTML it *appears* you have multiple nodes at various locations.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are appending the elements dynamically to the page. But the event handler(`elementContainer.addEventListener('click', onClick());`) is added before the element is rendered on the page.

So the thing with dynamic elements is that, you have to add its handlers dynamically too.

To do this, simply change your lines from this-

```
var elementContainer = document.createElement('option');
elementContainer.innerHTML = '<span>'+ self.name + '    ' + self.preis.toFixed(2) + '€</span>';
elementContainer.addEventListener('click', onClick());
```

into this line -

```
var elementContainer = '<option onclick="onClick()"><span>'+ self.name + '    '+self.preis.toFixed(2) + '€<span><option>';
```

**UPDATE**

then you can modify your `render()` function and put the returned string in the `self.pizzaPreviewElement.innerHTML` instead of using `self.pizzaPreviewElement.appendChild(element);`

Just make sure that the function `onClick()` exixts before you append the element to the page.

Comment: This stops my render method from running, as appendChild is no longer possible if I do not use createElement first and that one does not take the addition of onclick as valid data.

Comment: Does it have to be a Select/Option element?  Personally I'd use a UL/LI (unless you need the dropdown behaviour) but in any case, attach the click event to the UL, not the LI.  You can then add/remove as many LIs as and when you like without tonnes of event listeners.  On click, get the target of the event and use target.parentNode.removeChild(target) to delete.